# Postgres regex match incorrect in trigger

Tags: regex, postgresql, rspec-rails

I have a INSERT trigger with a regex check that is not returning my expected result... but *only* when run in a trigger. When run from my SQL editor it works as expected.

Failing trigger code (I added the `RAISE` to troubleshoot the problem, the code I am trying to get to work is the `IF` statement below):

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'postal_code regex check %', '55555' !~* '^\d{5}$';
IF NEW.postal_code !~* '^\d{5}$' THEN
  errors := ARRAY_APPEND(errors, 'Postal code format is invalid.');
END IF;
```

This is the exception thrown (I expect the `t` to be`f`):

```
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::RaiseException:
 #   ERROR:  postal_code regex check t
```

If I just run this in my SQL editor directly:

```
select '55555' !~* '^\d{5}$';
```

it returns `false` as expected.

Postgres 9.6

UPDATE: I tried to isolate this problem but was unable to reproduce with the following (if this was showing the problem, the `select count(*)` should return 0 but it returns 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
    postal_code varchar
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_postal_code() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$
        DECLARE

        BEGIN
          IF NEW.postal_code !~* '^\d{5}$' THEN
            RETURN false;
          END IF;

          RETURN NEW;
        END;
      $_$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS validate_postal_code_trigger on my_table;
CREATE TRIGGER validate_postal_code_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_postal_code();

insert into my_table values ('55555');

select count(*) from my_table;
```

Comment: I have another question, why is it `t`?

Comment: t = true, f = false unless I'm missing something

Comment: Are you sure that `t` denotes true? or you guess?

Comment: It's a good question - however I believe `t` is true.  If I `select true;` it prints out `t`

Comment: Did you try to reverse the result `RAISE EXCEPTION 'postal_code regex check %', '55555' ~* '^\d{5}$';` ?

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet - it returns `ERROR:  postal_code regex check f` in the trigger and `t` from the sql editor...

Comment: And what is the result of `do $$ begin RAISE EXCEPTION 'postal_code regex check %', '55555' !~* '^\d{5}$'; end $$;`? (It is `ERROR:  postal_code regex check f` here, as expected)

Comment: However my guess is: It is error message from some other source. Try to add more diagnostics info, for example: `RAISE EXCEPTION 'Debug--> postal_code regex check %, %', '55555' !~* '^\d{5}$', NEW;`

Comment: @Abelisto the `$$ ... $$` is `f` as expected... I created a completely discrete test case and unfortunately cannot reproduce (updated question with the isolated test case). The context here is that this is running in a rails test. I did drop the schema and recreate but am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Had never used Rails, so my last guess here: probably it implicitly escapes some characters? Try the simpler regex, like `'55555' !~* '\d\d\d\d\d'`, `'55555' !~* '[0-9]{5}'` and so on. God luck!

Comment: a little confused here. the goal is to insert rows only if the postal code matches the pattern `^\d{5}$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was The Rails migration adding the trigger was stripping the backslash from the regular expression.

Using this syntax in the migration:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_postal_code() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
        DECLARE

        BEGIN
          IF NEW.postal_code !~ '^\d{5}$' THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Debug--> postal_code regex check %, %, %', NEW.postal_code !~* '^\d{5}$', TG_OP, NEW.postal_code;
          END IF;
          RETURN NEW;
        END;
      $$;

  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS validate_postal_code_trigger on my_table;
  CREATE TRIGGER validate_postal_code_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_postal_code();
SQL

execute sql
```

in a Rails migration was stripping out the backslash in my regular expression. The actual regex that was being applied to the database was `'^d{5}$'` (missing the backslash) instead of `'^\d{5}$'`.